# Android espresso test fast emulator

Tags: android, software-testing, android-emulator

Most times I try recording android espresso test on the android studio in built emulator, but due to the very slow response rate of the emulator. I find it almost impossible to record a test successfully. Is the a third party emulator that is usable or is there a way to make the in-built emulator work faster?
N.b. the emulator work flawlessly in other areas